# O .click() não poderia servir como manipulador de função já que só funciona com function() para ser executado?

Tags: jquery

Estive lendo a documentação do `jQuery` pois surgiu uma dúvida sobre o uso de [**.click()**](https://api.jquery.com/click/) e não encontrei nada além do uso de [**.click()**](https://api.jquery.com/click/) com o handler [function()](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Function) se na documentação não tem mais nada para servir além de manipuladores de eventos, porque não usar o `.click()` e executar uma função por si só, sem o uso de `function()`, já que ele se justifica por existir somente com o uso de `function()` nele?

Ao invés de:

```
<script>
<p>MEU PÊ</p>

$( "p" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).slideUp();
});
</script>
```

Seria:

```
<script>
<p>MEU PÊ</p>

$( "p" ).click() {
  $( this ).slideUp();
}
</script>
```

Pois se na própria documentação não tem referências e não tem exemplos e a própria documentação está:

> Descrição: vincule um manipulador de eventos ao evento JavaScript
>   "clique" ou acione esse evento em um elemento.

Comment: O `.click()` já é um método nativo do JS.

Comment: @Sam me refiro ao function() dentro de click(), se o click() usa manipulador function() para explicar sua existência, porque não ter o click() com o manipulador função já incluso, ex: $("p").click(function(){ ....... }); poderia ser apenas $("p").click(){ ....... };

Comment: @EliseuB. veja a resposta do LipESprY. Mas de forma resumida: se fizesse do jeito que você espera, você estaria executando a função no mesmo momento, mas não é essa a ideia do "click", o que ele faz é armazenar a função (por isso que a function é passada como parâmetro) para ser executada só quando o usuário clicar no elemento.

Comment: @JúlioNeto mas a idéia é essa, executar a função quando houver um clique, a dúvida é porque ela não é uma função em si e tem dependência de function() para que o evento funcione, já que é só isso que ela faz, chamar a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "*- porque não usar o **.click()** e executar uma função por si só, sem o uso de function()*"

## Resposta rápida

Você está querendo "definir o método" já na sua própria execução. Isso está errado! Não foi feito assim <strike>e devemos nos conformar</strike>!

Esta forma **é incorreta**:

```
$( "p" ).click() {
  $( this ).slideUp();
}
```

---

## Sobre o método `.click()`

O `click()` é um método do JavaScript para qualquer `HTMLElementObject` (elementos HTML), **MAS** seu comportamento é diferente quando está atrelado a um objeto jQuery.

- **JavaScript puro:**

O método `.click()` simula um clique no objeto - como se o usuário estivesse apontando o mouse e clicando. Veja:

```js
document.getElementById('botao').addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(){
        document.getElementById('checkbox').click(); // <<<<
    },
    false
);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<button type="button" id="botao">Clique aqui</button>
```

---

- **JavaScript com jQuery:**

O método `.click()`, quando em um objeto jQuery, **captura** o evento `click` e executa um handler (semelhante a uma *callback*) que deve ser passado como argumento. Veja:

```js
function myScript(){
    alert('Executou myScript()!');
}
$('#btnClick').click(myScript);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btnClick">Clique!</button>
```

---

Da forma que você exemplificou é "como se fosse uma forma curta" de definir o *handler*:

```
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).slideUp();
});
```

Você pode utilizar de ambas as formas. Isso convém ao seu projeto. Se vai utilizar a mesma "`function(){}`" como *handler* de vários eventos, ideal é você utilizar da primeira forma - definindo uma função e posteriormente invocando-a dentro do método `.click()`. Mas, se você vai utilizar esse bloco de código uma única vez, porque não colocá-lo diretamente dentro do método!? ;D

Perceba, também, que desta forma não pode ser definido argumentos na chamada da função! Se houver, deve, novamente, voltar ao bloco `function(){ foo(arg1, arg2); }`.

---

## Variações

Como estamos falando especificamente do evento `click`, por que não comentar as várias forma válidas?!

- Direto no elemento:

  ```
    <element onclick="myScript">
  ```
- Em JavaScript puro:

  ```
    object.onclick = function(){myScript};
  ```
- Em JavaScript puro - usando o método `addEventListener` (*não funciona em Internet Explorer <= 8*):

  ```
    object.addEventListener("click", myScript);
  ```
- Em JavaScript com jQuery - usando o método `on`:

  ```
    $('#id').on('click', myScript);
  ```

Obs.: nos 3 exemplos acima, `myScript` é a chamada da função...

> Leitura recomendada: [W3Schools: onclick Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) (em inglês)
>
> Leitura recomendada: [W3Schools: HTML DOM click() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp) (em inglês)
>
> Leitura recomendada: [jQuery .click() Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/) (em inglês)

Comment: É essa a resposta que sanou minha dúvida, acreditava que .click() tinha mais algum motivo em jQuery para não ser o próprio evento da função, e explicando como é em javascript ficou tudo bem esclarecido. Obrigado!