# Função alert não está sendo executada ao clicar no botão

Tags: javascript, html

Ao digitar o texto nos `input` e clicar no botão, a função `alert()` não executa!

Meu código:

```html
    <html lang="pt">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 <h1>Teste Javascript</h1>
 <div id="app">
  <input type="text" name="nome" />
  <input type="text" name="nome2" />
  <button class="botao">Pressione aqui</button>
 </div>
 <script>
  var inputElement = document.querySelector('input[name=nome2]');
  var btnElement = document.querySelector('button.botao');
               btnElement.onClick = function(){
         var text = inputElement.value;
         alert(text);
            }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Qual o problema?

Comment: Antes de mais nada [edit] sua pergunta e [poste seu código como texto, ao invés de imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/45810)...

Comment: Pronto! Desculpa a demora, tava trabalhando fora. 
Obrigado pela ajuda !! valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nomenclatura esta errada, altere sua função para `btnElement.onclick = function () {...`

Uma outra forma de trabalhar seria criar um listener

```
btnElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  função...
});
```

> Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Ué, mas é exatamente a mesma resposta que já foi postada 1 hora atrás

Comment: Minha intenção foi mostrar tbm uma outra forma de trabalhar.

Comment: Essa outra forma já foi mencionada na minha outra resposta. Tanto que recomendei leitura dela. xD

Answer (score 1):

Na linha `20`, altere `onClick` para `onclick` e seu `alert()` irá funcionar!

> Leitura recomendada: [minha resposta sobre o evento `click`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367912/45810).

Answer (score -2):

```js
 
  $(document).on("click",".botao",function() {
  var input1 = $('input[name="nome"]').val();
  alert(input1);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="nome"/>
<button type="button" class="botao">Ok</button>
```

Comment: Tente explicar o seu código faz